# ionic / angular2 dynamically close FABs

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, floating-action-button

Using ionic's FABS but in a loop, so can not use id for retrieving component and close:

```
<ion-item ion-item *ngFor="let e of elements">
    <ion-fab top right>
        <button ion-fab mini><ion-icon name="more"></ion-icon></button>
        <ion-fab-list side="bottom">
            <button ion-fab (click)="click(e)"><ion-icon name='create'></ion-icon></button>
        </ion-fab-list>
    </ion-fab>
</ion-item>
```

The standard solution for closing FABs require an ID on ION-FAB, then can access outer ION-FAB component and call .close():

```
    <ion-fab top right #fab>
        <button ion-fab mini><ion-icon name="more"></ion-icon></button>
        <ion-fab-list side="bottom">
            <button ion-fab (click)="click(fab,e)"><ion-icon name='create'></ion-icon></button>
        </ion-fab-list>
    </ion-fab>
```

Since these fabs are dynamically generated I can not provide an ID and don't know how to access the parent ION-FAB Component from inner button event, so how can I access parent FAB component to call .close() on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this
**HTML**

```
<ion-fab top right *ngFor="let e of elements; let currentIndex = index;"
[style.margin-left.px]="currentIndex*45" #fabList>
        <button ion-fab mini id="{{'fab_btn'+ currentIndex}}"><ion-icon name="more"></ion-icon></button>
        <ion-fab-list side="bottom">
            <button ion-fab (click)="click(currentIndex)"><ion-icon name='create'></ion-icon></button>
        </ion-fab-list>
</ion-fab>
```

**Typescript**

```
import { ViewChildren, QueryList } from '@angular/core';

@ViewChildren('fabList')fabList : QueryList<FabContainer>; //Use @ViewChildren instead of @ViewChild

click(currentIndex: any) {
    //let id = 'fab_btn' + currentIndex.toString();
    //document.getElementById(id).click();
    let currentFab: FabContainer = this.fabList._results[index]; //Get current clicked FabContainer object from index 
    currentFab.close(); 
}
```

**Demo** - https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-fab-tab-open-niy8wg-close-dynamically-utrxfs?file=pages/home/home.ts

Comment: seems that you simulate a click with a custom ID from the inner list to the outer button, but the problem is to close the fab list when clicking on the fab button, something like being able to do ion-fab (outer fab not button) .close()

Comment: You said 'close the fab-list when clicking on the fab button' but it's the default functionality of `ion-fab`. when you click on `ion-fab` it will automatically close `ion-fab-list`.

Comment: when I tried it did not do this, in the documentation specify to do it manually https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/fab/FabContainer/ search for fab.close() , I want to do this but it states I need an instance of the container and don't know how to refer it in a loop

Comment: So you want to close `fab-list` only using `fab.close();`?

Comment: Refer the demo link, open one of `fab-list` and click on last `close` button it will close current opened `fab-list`. so what's the functionality difference ?

Comment: actually, I workarounded, but still the original solution is not working by simply click and need fab.close() as in documentation example: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/fab/FabContainer/ , to made it work nicely I need to have the instance of the closest FabContainer

Comment: For `FabContainer` object you need to iterate dynamic value for `ViewChild`.

Comment: how to know trhe one that is the ancestor of the actual button?

Comment: Yeah that's the main problem how to generate unique `ViewChild`. actually I tried this solution but I stuck at this problem so solve using click event with `id`.

Comment: @Luca, I think we can use `@ViewChildren` instead of `@ViewChild`. see this demo link https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-fab-tab-open-niy8wg-close-dynamically-utrxfs?file=pages/home/home.ts

Comment: hello, it seem work, if you puti in answer I would accept it